# Where are function constants stored if a function is created inside another function?

Tags: r

I am using a parent function to generate a child function by returning the function in the parent function call. The purpose of the parent function is to set a constant (y) in the child function. Below is a MWE. When I try to debug the child function I cannot figure out in which environment the variable is stored in.

```
power=function(y){
  return(function(x){return(x^y)})
}

square=power(2)

debug(square)

square(3)

debugging in: square(3)
debug at #2: {
    return(x^y)
}

Browse[2]> x
[1] 3
Browse[2]> y
[1] 2
Browse[2]> ls()
[1] "x"
Browse[2]> find('y')
character(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspect the type of an R function, you’ll observe the following:

```
> typeof(square)
[1] "closure"
```

And that is, in fact, exactly the answer to your question: [a *closure* is a function that carries an environment around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

R also tells you *which* environment this is (albeit not in a terribly useful way):

```
> square
function(x){return(x^y)}
<environment: 0x7ffd9218e578>
```

(The exact number will differ with each run — it’s just a memory address.)

Now, which environment does this correspond to? It corresponds to a local environment that was created when we executed `power(2)` (a “[stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers)”). As the other answer says, it’s now the parent environment of the `square` function (in fact, in R *every function*, except for certain builtins, is associated with a parent environment):

```
> ls(environment(square))
[1] "y"
> environment(square)$y
[1] 2
```

You can read more about environments in the chapter in [Hadley’s *Advanced R* book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

---

Incidentally, closures are a core feature of *functional programming languages*. Another core feature of functional languages is that *every expression is a value* — and, by implication, a function’s (return) value is the value of its last expression. This means that using the `return` function in R is both unnecessary *and misleading!*<sup>1</sup> You should therefore leave it out: this results in shorter, more readable code:

```
power = function (y) {
  function (x) x ^ y
}
```

There’s another R specific subtlety here: since arguments are evaluated lazily, your function definition is error-prone:

```
> two = 2
> square = power(two)
> two = 10
> square(5)
[1] 9765625
```

Oops! Subsequent modifications of the variable `two` are reflected inside `square` (but only the first time! Further redefinitions won’t change anything). To guard against this, use the [`force` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/force.html):

```
power = function (y) {
  force(y)
  function (x) x ^ y
}
```

`force` simply forces the evaluation of an argument name, nothing more.

---

<sup>1</sup> Misleading, because `return` is a *function* in R and carries a slightly different meaning compared to procedural languages: it *aborts* the current function exectuion.

Comment: This helps a lot. Is there a way to make the square function independent of its environment? Somehow substitute y with the value so that the square function does not have to search in its environment. I am using the square function as a R6 field and upon cloning R6 replaces the environments of its fields.

Comment: @ak17 Functions in R fundamentally always have an environment associated so, no, you cannot make them independent. However, you *can* substitute the variable’s use by its value in your case by using term rewriting, e.g. via the [`unenclose` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pryr/versions/0.1.4/topics/unenclose) from the {pryr} package. This is fairly advanced. Incidentally, your example is exactly the same example that Hadley uses to demonstrate `unenclose` in his [“Functional Programming” chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html).

Answer (score 3):

The variable `y` is stored in the parent environment of the function. The `environment()` function returns the current environment, and we use `parent.env()` to get the parent environment of a particular environment.

```
ls(envir=parent.env(environment())) #when using the browser
```

The `find()` function doesn't seem helpful in this case because it seems to only search objects that have been attached to the global search path (`search()`). It doesn't try to resolve variable names in the current scope.

Comment: I was about to say `ls(envir = environment(square))`. Could you explain why there is no need for the argument to `environment`? Upvote, anyway.

Comment: `environment()` returns the "current" executing environment. It doesn't need a parameter in this case because we just want the environment for the function we are currently running.